# RSS Feeds are not getti ng update automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, rss-reader

I have set up a blog on a subdomain. like blog.mywebsite.com

And I have set up a recent posts widget using RSS Feed on my main website's homepage.

I have managed to display the most recent 3 posts in that widget.

But now when I add a new post on the subdomain blog site that widget is not getting updated. It is showing only old posts.

I used this tutorial to set up the widget. https://www.worldoweb.co.uk/2012/display-wordpress-posts-on-another-wp-blog

The actual PHP Code I am using on my website is below.

```
<?php
//replace with your URL
$rss = fetch_feed('https://blog.mywebsite.com/feed/');

if (!is_wp_error($rss)) :

    $maxitems = $rss -> get_item_quantity(3); //gets latest 3 items This can be changed to suit your requirements
    $rss_items = $rss -> get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
?>
<?php
//shortens description
function shorten($string, $length) {
    $suffix = '&hellip;';
    $short_desc = trim(str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), ' ', strip_tags($string)));
    $desc = trim(substr($short_desc, 0, $length));
    $lastchar = substr($desc, -1, 1);
    if ($lastchar == '.' || $lastchar == '!' || $lastchar == '?')
        $suffix = '';
        $desc .= $suffix;
    return $desc;
}
?>
<!--start of displaying our feeds-->
<ul class="rss-items" id="wow-feed">
<?php
        if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
        else foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :
?>
<li class="item">
    <span class="data">
            <h3><a href='<?php echo esc_url($item -> get_permalink()); ?>' title='<?php echo esc_html($item -> get_title()); ?>'> <?php echo esc_html($item -> get_title()); ?></a></h3>
        <span class="date-image">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="rtin-date"><?php echo $item -> get_date('F j, Y'); ?></div>
        <p class="rtin-content"><?php echo shorten($item -> get_description(), '120'); ?></p>
    </span>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is.

when i add new post to my blog it should show in that RSS widget too.

Comment: What if you call the Feed URL in the browser? Do you see the new article?

Comment: Have you verified the output of `is_wp_error($rss)`

Comment: This could be a widget cache issue, make a change to the widget then update it and see if it shows the latest posts after an update. if yes then look for a cache plugin or something similar that is applying cache on widgets.

Comment: Thank you for your Help. Actually, it is working fine. The widget is getting updated but it is not showing the latest post on the same day I have posted it.
For example, if I added a post today widget will show it tomorrow. So that is OK for me. Thank you.